# can a faulty hard disk make my CPU IDLE so low

Tags: linux, hard-drive, cpu, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel

we have couple RHEL servers ( RHEL version 7.2 ) with very low CPU idle as the following.

our suspicion is about the disks as for example sdk and sdc and that because we saw from dmesg errors as `[sdk] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error`

here the details from `sar` command that show the CPU IDLE values

```
    09:43:56 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
    09:44:01 AM     all     98.57      0.00      0.62      0.00      0.00      0.80
    09:44:06 AM     all     98.26      0.00      0.92      0.01      0.00      0.81
    09:44:11 AM     all     97.29      0.00      1.66      0.01      0.00      1.03
    09:44:16 AM     all     92.81      0.00      6.06      0.03      0.00      1.10
    09:44:21 AM     all     92.31      0.00      6.43      0.05      0.00      1.21
    Average:        all     95.85      0.00      3.14      0.02      0.00      0.99


09:44:21 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
09:44:22 AM     all     96.52      0.00      3.10      0.00      0.00      0.38
09:44:22 AM       0     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       1     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       2    100.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       3     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       4     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       5     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       6     97.98      0.00      2.02      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       7     97.98      0.00      2.02      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       8     98.99      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM       9     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      10     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      11     98.02      0.00      0.99      0.00      0.00      0.99
09:44:22 AM      12     97.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00      2.00
09:44:22 AM      13     96.97      0.00      3.03      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      14     98.02      0.00      0.99      0.00      0.00      0.99
09:44:22 AM      15     94.00      0.00      6.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      16     83.00      0.00     16.00      0.00      0.00      1.00
09:44:22 AM      17     98.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00      1.00
09:44:22 AM      18     96.97      0.00      2.02      0.00      0.00      1.01
09:44:22 AM      19     96.00      0.00      4.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      20     97.98      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      1.01
09:44:22 AM      21     95.05      0.00      4.95      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      22     94.95      0.00      5.05      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      23     98.99      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      24     98.99      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      25     99.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      26     98.99      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      27     98.99      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      28     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      29     98.00      0.00      2.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      30     94.95      0.00      5.05      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      31     97.03      0.00      1.98      0.00      0.00      0.99
09:44:22 AM      32     98.02      0.00      1.98      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      33     99.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      34     98.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00      1.00
09:44:22 AM      35     97.98      0.00      2.02      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      36     94.00      0.00      5.00      0.00      0.00      1.00
09:44:22 AM      37     98.02      0.00      0.99      0.00      0.00      0.99
09:44:22 AM      38     97.98      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      1.01
09:44:22 AM      39     89.00      0.00     11.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      40     83.00      0.00     13.00      0.00      0.00      4.00
09:44:22 AM      41     97.00      0.00      3.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      42     91.92      0.00      8.08      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      43     94.06      0.00      5.94      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      44     92.93      0.00      7.07      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      45     97.00      0.00      3.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      46     99.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:22 AM      47     98.99      0.00      1.01      0.00      0.00      0.00

sar -B 2 5

09:44:24 AM  pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff
09:44:26 AM  14852.00  71776.00 101443.50      0.00 216420.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:28 AM  14336.00    184.00   5123.00      0.00  47167.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:30 AM  14418.00 203778.00  67194.50      0.00 132952.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:32 AM  14352.00 220796.00   2475.00      0.00  59666.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
09:44:34 AM  13318.00  56996.00  16290.00      0.00   9599.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:     14255.20 110706.00  38505.20      0.00  93161.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

from `vmstat` command

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
65  0 3505188 6265864 4828612 304096576    0    0   137   127    0    0 49  1 50  0  0
63  1 3505188 6068484 4828660 304294848    0    0 12292 41500 95782 88751 98  2  1  0  0
66  0 3505188 5933464 4828672 304429248    0    0 14668 130968 85788 90844 97  2  1  0  0
```

r: The number of processes waiting for run time.

from kernel messages we get:

```
[117426425.532990] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdc, sector 116127985
[117426431.038365] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[117426431.038374] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
[117426431.038378] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[117426431.038383] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 06 eb f8 f0 00 00 00 08 00 00
[117426431.038386] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdc, sector 116127985
[139602560.596832] traps: polkitd[27641] general protection ip:7f7996318cf2 sp:7ffe7a28e5b0 error:0 in libmozjs-17.0.so[7f79961da000+3b3000]
[144770588.094226] sd 0:0:11:0: [sdk] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[144770588.094238] sd 0:0:11:0: [sdk] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor] 
[144770588.094242] sd 0:0:11:0: [sdk] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[144770588.094248] sd 0:0:11:0: [sdk] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 01 15 20 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
```

so based on above output is it make sense that the root cause of very low CPU IDLE is because disks errors as we get from kernel messages ?

Note - on machine we not have Insufficient RAM memory. and memory available are enough

related links

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-could-reasons-low-cpu-usage-chandan-kumar/

Comment: If anything a failing HDD would cause the CPU usage to increase not decrease.

Comment: I am talking about CPU IDLE not CPU util that opposite to CPU IDLE

Comment: This is most confusing. If you are talking about an App or Measurement and not actual CPU usage, then HDD errors likely have nothing to do with the App (unless - low chance) the error is where the App is on disk.

Comment: we are running spark application on disk

Comment: The app may be confused too.

Comment: I not understand what you means.  , in any case spark application are running and from dmesg we have maybe disks problem and my question was if disks can caused very low cpu idle

Comment: To clear up to confusion, by "very low cpu idle" do you mean "high CPU usage"?

Comment: yes , very low cpu idle is actually very high cpu usage.

Comment: The App may have issues with the HDD errors

Comment: what you means about "The App may have issues with the HDD errors " , from dmesg we can see bad messages about the disks so it seems pure disks problem

Comment: do you means that faulty disks as described from dmesg should be replaced?  and disks are the root cause for very high CPU Util ?

Comment: I would not keep bad disks in use.

Comment: but do you agree with me about what I said? I means disks caused high cpu util

Comment: You should edit your question and use common easily understandable vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

A bad disk is a very possible cause for high CPU utilization.

A discovered read error will cause the filesystem using the CPU to try to recover and map out that failed read; i.e. read back the data, mark the bad portion of the disk as "not usable", and store any recovered data elsewhere on the disk.

*Note: This is likely to escalate with time; more and more of the disk fails... more and more work required to map out bad disk area*

Comment: in my question I mentioned the CPU IDLE that is very low , that actually is opposite to cpu Utilization , so CPU IDLE values is like CPU Utilization high values